# Sendmail very slow - /etc/hosts configuration

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sendmail

It takes ~15 seconds to send single e-mail using sendmail.

**/var/log/mail.log:**

```
Jul 31 09:52:42 piotr-probook sendmail[2912]: My unqualified host name (piotr-probook) unknown; sleeping for retry
```

**/etc/hostname:**

```
piotr-probook
```

**/etc/hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1   piotr-probook localdev localhost
192.168.1.1 router
```

**/etc/mail/sendmail.cf:**

```
# hosts file (normally /etc/hosts)
O HostsFile=/etc/hosts
```

Obviously I can ping `piotr-probook` host and HTTP server popups in browser when i type url `http://piotr-probook`

What am I doing wrong? How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sendmail requires that the result of "hostname" be a fully qualified domain name to start cleanly.

Set the hostname to something like piotr-probook.localdomain and update /etc/hosts.

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   piotr-probook.localdomain piotr-probook localdev localhost
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! Btw. it works without changing machine hostname. I just added `piotr-probook.localdomain` to /etc/hosts and everything is ok

Comment: Thanks so much, Btw, I add a newline `127.0.0.1 piotr-probook.localdomain` seems not work, but merge it to ONE line, it works!!